What is a correlation function of renormalized currents in QED?
The correlation function
$$
\langle\beta|\mathcal{T}J(x_1)\cdots J(x_n)|\alpha\rangle,\tag{1}
$$
where $J^\mu=e\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi$ is the QED current, is usually interpreted as the diagram of the process $\alpha\rightarrow\beta$ with $n$ photon-electron vertices inserted. See for example, [Weinberg] eq.(10.5.1) and [Schwartz] eq.(14.150). This is usually derived from the Schwinger-Dyson equation. My problem is related to the derivation based on the renormalized QED Lagrangian.
The renormalized QED Lagrangian is
$$
\mathcal{L}= - \frac{1}{4}Z_3 F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2\xi}(\partial_{\mu} A^\mu)^2
+ Z_2 i \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi - Z_2Z_m m\bar{\psi}\psi
+ Z_1 e\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu A_\mu\psi.\tag{2}
$$
The corresponding Euler-Lagrangian equation is
$$
0=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial A_\mu}-\partial_\nu\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\nu A_\mu)}
=Z_1J^\mu
-(-Z_3 g^{\mu\nu}\partial^2+(Z_3-\xi^{-1})\partial^\mu\partial^\nu)A_\nu.\tag{3}
$$
Plugging this into the Schwinger-Dyson equation gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(-Z_3 g^{\mu\nu}\partial^2+(Z_3-\xi^{-1})\partial^\mu\partial^\nu)\langle\Omega|\mathcal{T}A_\nu(x)\cdots|\Omega\rangle\\
&=Z_1\langle\Omega|\mathcal{T}J^\mu (x)\cdots|\Omega\rangle+\text{contact terms}.
\end{aligned}\tag{4}
$$
(See also this Phys.SE post.) Splitting the left hand side of this formula gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(-g^{\mu\nu}\partial^2+(1-\xi^{-1})\partial^\mu\partial^\nu)\langle\Omega|\mathcal{T}A_\nu(x)\cdots|\Omega\rangle\\
&=Z_1\langle\Omega|\mathcal{T}J^\mu (x)\cdots|\Omega\rangle
-(Z_3-1)(-g^{\mu\nu}\partial^2+\partial^\mu\partial^\nu)\langle\Omega|\mathcal{T}A_\nu(x)\cdots|\Omega\rangle\\
&+\text{contact terms}.
\end{aligned}\tag{5}
$$
Now, the left hand side is an "LSZ operator" acting on an $A$ correlation function, which is the Feynman diagram with the external $A$ propagator amputated. But on the right hand side there is now a term propotional to $(Z_3-1)$, so the $J$ correlation function is not directly equal to the left hand side. Then how could we interpret this renormalized $J$ correlation function diagramatically? Or maybe only the bare $J$ correlation function has a simple diagramatical interpretation?

One of the reasons why I am wondering this question is that in the study of lepton-nucleon
inclusive deep inelastic scattering (DIS), we are dealing with $J$ correlation function like the hadronic tensor $W^{\mu\nu}\propto \langle P,S|J^\mu(x)J^\nu(0)|P,S\rangle$, which is the cross section of "virtual $\gamma^*$ $+$ nucleon $N$ $\rightarrow$ inclusive $X$" (see [Schwartz] eq.(32.78)). I am not clear whether the $J$ here is renormalized or not. If it is renormalized, the hadronic tensor expressed in terms of the $J$ correlation function is no longer equal to the amplitude we are considering since there is an extra $(Z_3-1)$ term in eq.(5). Or maybe we are considering only leading order QED in DIS, so we do not need renormalization of QED at all?
References:

[Weinberg] S. Weinberg, QFT, Vol. 1.
[Schwartz] M. D. Schwartz, QFT.

